# How to navigate dashboard when login successful in React native?

Tags: react-native, express, navigation

I have implemented some code in react native, to connect with the express backend. This only works for all the users without the role == admin. I could able to print the Successfully logged! in console. But now I need to navigate to the dashboard. How can I do that. I don't know how to do that. another thing is in the touchableOpacity I saw the attribute called value. But I can't find the meaning of that. Please help me in this regard. Also I have attach the service file also.

```
   import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

import {useTheme} from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import axios from 'axios';
import {hostName} from '../../constants/constants';
import {login} from '../../services/authService';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const SigninPage = ({navigation}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const {colors} = useTheme();

  const signIn = () => {
    login(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        // if (res.data.role == 'admin') {
        //   throw new Error('Cannot login');
        // } else {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data.dbResult[0]));
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userRole', res.data.role);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.token);
        console.log('successfully logged!');
        // }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000e60'}}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#009387" barStyle="light-content" />
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Animatable.Image
          animation="bounceIn"
          duraton="1500"
          source={require('../../assets/img/afisolve_logo.png')}
          style={styles.logo}
          resizeMode="stretch"
        />
      </View>
      <Animatable.View
        style={[
          styles.footer,
          {
            backgroundColor: colors.background,
          },
        ]}
        animation="fadeInUpBig">
        <Text style={styles.signinTop}>Sign in with your account</Text>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.TextInput}
            placeholder="Email"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.TextInput}
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={(password) => setPassword(password)}
          />
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => signIn()}>
          <LinearGradient colors={['#730018', '#00085b']} style={styles.signIn}>
            <Text style={styles.textSign}>SIGN IN</Text>
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>Fogot Your Password?</Text>
      </Animatable.View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SigninPage;
const {height} = Dimensions.get('screen');
const height_logo = height * 0.28;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    flex: 2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: height_logo,
    height: height_logo,
    borderRadius: 150 / 3,
  },

  footer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
    paddingVertical: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputView: {
    backgroundColor: '#2937f6',

    width: '70%',
    height: 45,
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textSign: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  signIn: {
    width: 150,
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  signinTop: {
    color: '#000000',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingBottom: 25,
  },
});
```

Service file

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {hostName} from '../constants/constants';

export const login = (email, password) => {
  return axios.post(hostName + '/authentication/login', {
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help you

```js
const signIn = () => {
    login(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        // if (res.data.role == 'admin') {
        //   throw new Error('Cannot login');
        // } else {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userData',                JSON.stringify(res.data.dbResult[0]));
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userRole', res.data.role);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.token);
        console.log('successfully logged!');
        
        //here 
        navigation.replace('Home');//if you don't wanna call login back 
        //else
        navigation.navigate('Home');
        
        
        // }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: This will help for me. But I have to change some of it. and I change it from,  navigation.replace('Home') ; to --------> navigation.navigate('Home'); it helps me to navigate after successfully logging process.

Answer (score 0):

I use this tutorial to implement the [Authentication flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow).

Basically, you retrieve your access token, then store it in redux/context. Your Navigator detects that the user has an access token and change the screens available.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good answer to my question. If someone got the same stuck, will help you following the corrected issue.

```
const signIn = () => {
    login(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        // if (res.data.role == 'admin') {
        //   throw new Error('Cannot login');
        // } else {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data.dbResult[0]));
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userRole', res.data.role);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.token);
        console.log('successfully logged!');
         navigation.navigate('Home');
        // }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```